# Views PHP: how to get the `end-date` value within `Global(PHP)`?

Tags: views

I am rewriting the output a view block with a `Global(PHP)` field from the module [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php), and one of the fields I am rewriting is a Date field.

The value for the field is : `2015 - 08:30 to 09:30`

I am looping through the fields and simply printing them to see the output:

`foreach ($data->field_field_item_timespot as $timeEntry) {
  $time = $timeEntry['raw']['value']; 
  print $time;
}`

This is the output: `2015-01-01 08:30:00`

The issue that I am having is that it is only printing the `start-date` of the field, when I need both `start-date` & `end-date`. I am specifying the `Date field` to display start and end date values, and it does in the view, but not inside the `Global(PHP)`.

Any ideas how to get the `end-date` value within `Global(PHP)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$time = $timeEntry['raw']['value']` == Start Date

`$time = $timeEntry['raw']['value2']`== End Date